# In WPF MVVM, how do you transfer an item from one listbox to another using a double-click?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, listbox

I want to double-click to copy an item from a "shopping list" to a "shopping cart" list box. Right now, my model just has ObservableCollection of strings for each list, but eventually the objects will get more complex.

The ViewModel is mapped to the view using a DataTemplate. Right now, I just have a "Session" property on my ViewModel that is exposing my Session object in my Model that contains both ObservableCollections.

I tried this...

```
<ListBox Name="listBoxShopList" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Session.Products}">
  <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}}">
      <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="ListBoxItemMouseDoubleClick"/>
    </Style>
  </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
<ListBox Name="listBoxCart" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Session.CartItems, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

From code-behind I do get the event and I can get the SelectedItem. But being new to MVVM, I cannot figure out how to add the item to the "Cart" collection. It seems like I should be able to access the ViewModel Session.CartItems directly since the View can. Is a parameterized command the way to go? If so, any recommended articles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your event handler code-behind you could get the ViewModel like this:

```
var viewModel = DataContext as <YourViewModelType>;
```

And then transfer the selected item to the cart.
The preferred way to do it would be using a command, like [`DelegateCommand`](http://relentlessdevelopment.wordpress.com/2010/03/30/simplified-mvvm-commanding-with-delegatecommand/).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I figured a command was the way to go. It seems like I need a parameter with the command, but I have only used parameter-less commands so far in WPF. I'll research and try it when I can.

Comment: Ok. I was able to get the command (preferred way) working. But it was nice to first go the easy way getting the view model from the data context. Thanks for sharing that syntax; I wasn't sure how to access that when mapping the view model through a data template. I'll flag this as the answer since it had that tip for the newbie. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well, you get your handler (a part of view code) called on double click. Good so far.

Now, you need to inform the VM that double-click happened (or better put some semantics here: selection changed, shopping cart accepted, etc.) by invoking a command (preferred way), or communicating with the VM through DataContext (easy way). Your VM can update the ObservableCollection as appropriate, and the view will get the changes through the usual binding.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Good to confirm I was on the right track.